# Can't map to <C-Insert>

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, gvim

I'm trying to use ac to copy the whole contents to the system clipboard in gVim. Putting this in my .vimrc isn't working:

```
nnoremap <leader>ac ggvG$<C-Insert>
```

If I manually press `ggvG$[Ctrl-Insert]` from normal mode, it works as expected: goes to the top, selects to the bottom, copies it all, and drops me in normal mode at the top of the file.

When I set `nnoremap <leader>ac ggvG$<C-Insert>` in my .vimrc, and then activate it (with `[Space]ac`), it selects from the top to the bottom, beeps an error, and then just sits there in visual mode with the whole file selected.
If I manually press `[Ctrl-Insert]` at that point, it finishes as expected. So I'm pretty sure vim's just not doing the `<C-Insert>` part.

I further tested by adding this `vnoremap <leader>ci <C-Insert>`.
I selected a word or a line in visual mode, activated that map, and got a beep and no copying. A manual `[Ctrl-Insert]` works fine.

So **why can't I map to `<C-Insert>`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`help c-insert` will tell you that `"*y` will do the same as `<C-Insert>`.

So try

```
nnoremap <leader>ac ggVG"*y
```

(using `V` as it makes more sense)

While I didn't check, Vim says it's a standard DOS mapping so

```
nmap <leader>ac ggVG<c-insert>
```

may work as well.

Comment: Thanks! Both of these worked:
`nmap <leader>ac gg<S-v>G<C-Insert>`
and
`nnoremap <leader>ac gg<S-v>G"*y`.
This one didn't, despite what the help file says:
`nnoremap <leader>ac gg<S-v>G<M-N><M-U>`.